# Android detect double finger long press

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, motionevent

I'm creating an aplication where I can draw on a picture. Drawing is achieved by a pictureView, canvas with a bitmap and a onTouchListener.
I want to add a feature that will undo the last action when there is a two finger **short** press.
I achieved it by doing this:

```
if(event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP ){
    //undo
}
```

And I want to undo all the drawing actions when there is a two finger **long** press.
I tried something like this, but it will detect only once.

```
if(event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN ){
    numberOfDown++;
        if(numberOfDown>100){
            //undo
        }
}
```

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: Have you tried comparing the time of `DOWN` v `UP`? `DOWN` will only be triggered once per finger.

Comment: I just tried and it is not completly what I wanted. It will now only undo all the action on release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether the action index starts at zero for the primary finger or the non-primary fingers, so you might need to flip these 0's to 1's.

```
if(event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN && event.getActionIndex()==0){
    mSecondFingerTimeDown = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

if(event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP && event.getActionIndex()==0 ){
    if ((System.currentTimeMillis()-mSecondFingerDownTime) >= LONG_PRESS_TIME_MILLIS)
        //long double-press action
    else
        //short double-press action
}
```

Comment: I realized that there's a case where the user puts one finger down for a while, then taps a second finger down (for a short time or long time) and releases it without releasing the first finger. This will register as a two-finger tap with this code, even though the first finger hasn't released yet. To avoid this case gets more complicated. In the above code, instead of doing the actions right away, store which kind of action (long tap or short) is pending, and store the time. When the first finger does ACTION_UP, check if it's within a small time to decide whether to do the pending action.